# How assign output of command to variable and how to read to values from that variable

Tags: groovy, gremlin

Please find the XML dump of the code.

<has_ParameterDef xsi:type="com.ibm.datastage.ai.dtm.ds:DSParameterDefSDO" xmi:id="23" sDOVersion="2.0.0" objectID="c2e76d84.19e49cb.chsnquq8h.jd4tufc.jo3m3o.skams1gf060la530ouii1o" lastModificationTimestamp="2021-12-02T15:14:51.995+0200" optimisticLockID="1" createdByUser="Dummy" creationTimestamp="2021-12-02T15:14:51.995+0200" modifiedByUser="Dummy" name="$DB_PASSWD" defaultValue="$PROJDEF" typeCode="String" oDBCType="Unknown" usage="In" displayCaption="DB_PASSWD" xmetaLockingRoot="c2e76d84.43058877.chsnqhsg5.cs7fdaq.m7nch8.jc6qehgp5krjj9achqsfl"/>

<has_ParameterDef xsi:type="com.ibm.datastage.ai.dtm.ds:DSParameterDefSDO" xmi:id="26" sDOVersion="2.0.0" objectID="c2e76d84.19e49cb.chsnquq8h.jd4srt0.it7rdm.cgomse975nvnp5ml81ktuo" lastModificationTimestamp="2021-12-02T15:14:51.995+0200" optimisticLockID="1" createdByUser="Dummy" creationTimestamp="2021-12-02T15:14:51.995+0200" modifiedByUser="Dummy" name="$ADM_PASSWORD" defaultValue="$PROJDEF" typeCode="String" oDBCType="Unknown" usage="In" displayCaption="ADM_PASSWORD" extendedType="Encrypted" xmetaLockingRoot="c2e76d84.43058877.chsnqhsg5.cs7fdaq.m7nch8.jc6qehgp5krjj9achqsfl"/>

<has_ParameterDef xsi:type="com.ibm.datastage.ai.dtm.ds:DSParameterDefSDO" xmi:id="24" sDOVersion="2.0.0" objectID="c2e76d84.19e49cb.chsnquq8h.jd4tooe.adphau.qtm9uhskecsvc2jbl3cjuo" lastModificationTimestamp="2021-12-02T15:14:51.995+0200" optimisticLockID="1" createdByUser="Dummy" creationTimestamp="2021-12-02T15:14:51.995+0200" modifiedByUser="Dummy" name="$DB_USERNAME" defaultValue="$PROJDEF" typeCode="String" oDBCType="Unknown" usage="In" displayCaption="DB_USERNAME" xmetaLockingRoot="c2e76d84.43058877.chsnqhsg5.cs7fdaq.m7nch8.jc6qehgp5krjj9achqsfl"/>

There are three variables( DB_PASSWD,ADM_PASSWORD,DB_USERNAME) in the above XML dump. The variable DB_PASSWD contains string PASSWD but does not contain extendedType="Encrypted" like other variable 'ADM_PASSWORD'. so we want to capture variables which are having keywords like ('PASSWORD','PASSWD','PWD') but not having extendedType="Encrypted"

Comment: This is really a Groovy question not a Gremlin one as that is the Groovy closure syntax. You will need to add an additional Groovy filter to the closure or use a Gremlin `map` with a closure and filter on that. In general use of closures is discouraged as not all TinkerPop implementations allow them.

Comment: Can you add the Gremlin query you are trying to get working to the question? It should be possible to do this all in Gremlin using `TextP.containing`.

Comment: Hi @KelvinLawrence, 
I have updated requirement with more details.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm now totally lost. How is this related to Gremlin or graph databases? Do you have this data in a graph? The example you posted in the comment above looks like basic Groovy. Are you wanting help with Gremlin or Groovy?

Comment: Hi, I need hep in gremlin. I have generated XML based on graph. Graph contains properties along with vertices and edges.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.